# Magento Shopping Cart Rule Based on Grand Total?

Tags: magento

I was wondering if anyone knew how to set up a shopping cart rule to apply only if the grand total of the cart is >= some certain value.  I see that Magento allows you to set up rules based on the subtotal, but never on the grand total.
Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks.  By the way, we are using Magento Enterprise edition version 1.10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Without modification Magento does not allow this.

Shopping Cart Price Rules are applied on the cart, whereas a grand total is often not calculated until the last stage of the checkout. Two very different touch points. This would be exceedingly difficult to do, and I can't even begin to think where you would start.

Comment: Thanks Mike for confirming this for me (and for explaining the reasoning behind it).  I really appreciate it.